# How to get a list of the machine's IP addresses from Rust?

Tags: network-programming, rust

Specifically, I am interested in a programmatic way for acquiring a list of IP addresses such as those returned by `ifconfig`.

Preferably, the solution would be cross-platform.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out the [pnet crate](https://docs.rs/pnet/):

```
extern crate pnet;

use pnet::datalink;

fn main() {
    for iface in datalink::interfaces() {
        println!("{:?}", iface.ips);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but for those trying this today you might get an error 'no datalink in the root' on the use pnet::datalink line.  It seems this is broken in version 0.31.0.  Simply change your cargo.toml file to use 0.30.0


[dependencies]
pnet = "0.30.0"

Comment: Donno if this is supposed to work on Windows, I get a linker error: `note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Packet.lib'`. ---> found already the answer here below: https://docs.rs/crate/pnet