# Is there an easy way to get the system's external IP in Rust?

Tags: rust

I need to get my external IP from inside a Rust program. [In bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194136), an external source is needed, for example `curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`, I assume the same is true in Rust.

I did see [How to get a list of the machine's IP addresses from Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056006/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-machines-ip-addresses-from-rust), but it is related to the local IP not external.

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate of "making an HTTP request". As shown in [the first link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194136), an HTTP request is **one** possible solution. You can also shell out to command line tools, make a DNS request, use FTP, etc. I feel that this question is **too broad** as it should instead pick one of those mechanisms and look for the Rust equivalent. Getting it via HTTP is indeed a duplicate of the suggested Q&A.

Comment: @Shepmaster yes another part of the problem I'm facing... the change will be a pull request to another project. So if my PR completely relies on a site like `akamai.com` it will probably be ignored. I need to figure out a reliable long-term solution.